how to show two values in a same variable in php
I wanted define two values in a same variable.
At first was wrote same this:
<body>
    <a href="name.php?firstname=Tom&amp;lastname=schneider">Hi, I’m Tom schneider!</a>
</body>

and in php:
    <?php
    $name = $_GET['firstname' , 'lastname'];
    echo 'Herzlich Willkommen ' . $name . '!';
    ?>

And I had this error:
Parse error: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token ",", expecting "]" in /websites/default/public/name.php on line 9
next time I seperated the values:
$name = $_GET['firstname']['lastname'];

and thie error:
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in /websites/default/public/name.php on line 9
( ! ) TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in /websites/default/public/name.php on line 9
how can I set the values in  a same variables?

You probably want: $name = $_GET['firstname'] . $_GET['lastname'];

Seems like you're looking for $name = $_GET['firstname'] . ' ' .  $_GET['lastname'];

Difference between period and comma when concatenating with echo versus return?

If you are always going to receive firstname and lastname, and in this order, you can try the below:
<?php
$name = implode(' ', $_GET);
echo "Herzlich Willkommen {$name}!";
?>

implode(' ', $_GET) will join the elements of the $_GET array, which should always have the firstname and lastname properties. Perhaps that is something that will be validated in the frontend.

but $_GET is an associative array and in associative array is possible to save two or more strings. Right?

Yes. That is correct, hence I started with the statement "If you are always going to receive firstname and lastname, and in this order" and concluded with "Perhaps that is something that will be validated in the frontend."

First of all, retrieve each value separately from $_GET using the specific key name.
Secondly, concatenate the values (if that’s the intention) or store them in an array.
As mentioned above, just access it directly an concatenate it.
